# How can I add request header to the aws cloudfront url

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to add a reuqest header element to prevent using cloudfront url without this parameter.
Here is my fetching

```
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
             "header":value
        }
    }).then(res => res.blob())
        .then(blob => {
            const urlObject = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
           //set url to iframe
       })
```

How can I set this header value and check on AWS side?

Comment: it's not clear where you want to add the header. If it's in your XHR requests, then added it to your client-side code. If it's from CloudFront to your origin, you can use this feature to have CloudFront add the header to every request it makes to your origin— https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/add-origin-custom-headers.html

Comment: I want to add header to in my XHR request and Cloudfront side, I want to check that.

Comment: If you need to ensure the header is set on the request from the CloudFront side, you can do that using CloudFront Functions (a JavaScript function that CloudFront executes for you at each of its edge locations). See here for more info and example functions - https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-functions